# curve_fit performs poorly with bumpy data points

Tags: python, curve-fitting, least-squares, scipy-optimize

I have the following [data set](https://github.com/lucianodarriba/surface_density_fitting/blob/master/surf_dens_sim11.txt) which has several bumps and valleys. However, when I try to fit a curve with Python's `curve_fit` from `scipy` `optimize` module, it doesn't reproduce the bumps well. I tried 7-8th grade polynomials and sines, but I can't find something that fits well.

I assumed that with a 7-8th grade polynomial I should be able to reproduce those bumps (for a 7th-grade poly I'll have 3 bumps and 3 valleys, which should be enough), however, I only get 2 bumps with the fitting.

Is there a better way to fit functions in Python than `curve_fit`, or am I doing something wrong when fitting?

Thanks in advance for any solution you may give.

Comment: Python doesn't have a `curve_fit()` function—you must be using some extension module. Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: I now edited the question accordingly. However, without that clarification, for someone who is used to do curve fitting in Python knows what I was talking about.

Comment: It's not only useful to current readers, it may also be for future individuals with similar questions (so they can search more effectively).

Answer (score 2):

As I learned in school, polynomials are often quite a bad choise to fit to a curve (exact fitting, 10 mesure points result in a polynom of 9th grade). Sure, the curve makes sense at the 4 or 5 innermost points, but before and after its nowhere near the "real" values. Everything up to 4th or 5th grade can work, bur after that I recommend you look into splines. I assume `curve_fit` does not fit a polynom exactly to your mesure points, so this "could" work. Thing is, your messure points do not describe a polynom, and they didnt intend to I assume. 
Messure points from a falling rock or breaking car (distance over time) could be fitted very well (and should be) with a polynom of 2nd degree, because the base function is a polynom 2nd degree `s(t) = at^2 + v0t + s0`

TL;DR Polynom fitting is bad unless base function is polynom, here use spline fitting.

Answer (score 1):

You can get what looks to me an okish fit using higher degree polynomials. The image shows the fit from a degree 21 poly (green) and a degree 41 poly (blue) and the original (red).
While it is true that polynomials have their limitations, they often do fit reasonably.
[image: fits by least squares using orthogonal polynomials]

Comment: That looks excellent! What are you using to fit that?

Comment: @LucianoDarriba I used a home-made C function. There is nothing special about it. If you want I could describe it in may answer. This: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit  might be worth a try

Comment: No need. I tried that `numpy` method you gave me and worked like a charm! I don't know exactly why, but the `curve_fit` method from `scipy.optimize` doesn't yield the same polynomial. That was my struggle. Thanks friend!!! Now you have a special place in my heart! Have a nice day.